# Sync AutoCompleteTextView with a "submit" button

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am working with AutoCompleteTextView. I have added few items through Activity. After AutoCompleteTextView , I've given a "submit" button. I want to sync this button with AutoCompleteTextView . I want to click submit button when any item is selected and after clicking button, it should switch to that item's activity. Currently I don't have code with me. Please suggest me with any example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for AutoCompleteTextView

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] { "Belgium", "France",
        "Italy", "Germany", "Spain" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // In the onCreate method
    final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv_country);

    //EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    // textView.setThreshold(0);
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/actv_country"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >
</AutoCompleteTextView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I know this. I want to perform some action after clicking button, which can be selected after selecting any item from autocompletetextview.